# why a binary image become non-binary after reading?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, computer-vision

I print a row of my output image and it is binary obviously
[image]

However, when I read it in another function and print this row again, it becomes non-binary. What happened?

img = plt.imread(two_image,0)

print(img[100])
[image]

Comment: jpg does some compression which loose information.  You might want to use the png (or the gif) format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re probably saving it as a JPEG file, which is a lossy format. It changes the data slightly to be able to reduce the size on disk. To avoid this, save it as a PNG file.